# Has anyone ever ambushed Batman at the bat signal?

Tags: batman, dc-animated-universe, dc

I don't know if its location differs from canon to canon, but it's usually located on the roof of a GCPD station I think, so has anyone ever seen the signal, and just lain in wait to ambush Batman?

Comment: The Designated Love Interest Character used it in *Batman Forever* to try and get a booty call, but I don't think that was the kind of "ambush" you meant

Comment: @JasonBaker - Sex ambushes by Nicole Kidman are the best kind of ambushes.

Comment: http://media.comicbookmovie.com/images/users/uploads/33503/SuperiorSpider-Man3_4.jpg

Comment: @Richard I have yet to be sex ambushed by Nicole Kidman... one day!

Comment: Why would Batman show up at the roof by the signal, rather than call Commissioner Gordon or show up at their offices?

Comment: Just lay in wait, on the roof of a police station. Simple!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite you could lay in wait across the street with a high powered rifle

Comment: @Daft: Lie down across the street from a police station with a high-powered rifle. Another excellent idea!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite well you'd be hidden under a blanket or something...

Comment: @Daft: you’ve thought this through in some considerable detail. Are you... planning something???

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's surprisingly hard to find examples of villains using the Bat-signal at all, considering how obvious of a target it is; even then, most examples are just baddies manipulating the signal to send Batman a message. However, there are a handful of times it's been used as an ambush point<sup>1</sup>:

- In *Batman Confidential* #11, part of another version of the Joker's origin story, the Joker uses the newly-constructed Bat-signal to force a confrontation with his foe:

  [image: Joker at the Bat-signal]
  [image: Joker attacks]
- In *Batman and Robin*<sup>2</sup>, Poison Ivy uses a modified Bat-signal to attract Robin, intending to incapacitate him:

  [image: Poison Ivy's Robin-signal]
- In the DCAU movie *Batman: Mask of the Phantasm*, city councillor Arther Reeves *tries* to set up an ambush with the Bat-signal, but Batman doesn't take the bait.

---

<sup>1</sup> As I hint, I'm limiting my answer to occasions where someone is using the Bat-signal to lure a member of the Bat-family into a hazardous situation. There are more examples where the signal is used to communicate with Batman, either by a villain or a hero, but I'm not including those. I'm also not including occasions where individuals with non-villainous intent use the Bat-signal to get Batman's attention; I'm mostly throwing this in to exclude things like [Nicole Kidman sex-ambushes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVLp1.jpg)

<sup>2</sup> I apologize for reminding everyone that this movie existed.

Comment: "This is what happens when insanity goes insane." #ZING

Comment: "Batman and Robin..."  Hmm, "Batman and Robin."  No, no I don't recall any movie by that name.  Are you sure you're not making things up? Things that *should best be left alone?*

Comment: wow, the art in Batman Confidential #11 is really bad.

Comment: @Nerrolken it took real dedication for Jason to photoshop george clooney into a batman movie.

Comment: If you're including any member of the Bat-family, then there's also issue #15 of the 2009 _Batgirl_ series. Stephanie Brown answers the Bat-signal to find that she's been framed for murder and the police are waiting to arrest her.